# How to replace string "var num = ['asd23','asd31']" in powershell

Tags: powershell

Replace the give string

```
var num = ['red222','edr223']; //this value is always changing
```

as below

```
var num = ['rev11111','rev222']; //replace with any string
```

Tried:

```
num = @('rev11111','rev222') // text present in file say file.txt
(Get-Content "C:\file.txt").Replace('var num = *',"var num = ["+(@($Num) -join ",")+"];" )| Set-Content "C:\file.txt"
```

This did not help much. It cant replace when the `[` `]` are not empty. How to replace the string. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've to use the `-replace` operator and not the `Replace`-method of the string object. Since `Replace` doesn't support Regex.

If you change to:

```
$Num = @('rev11111','rev222') # text present in file say file.txt
(Get-Content "C:\temp\input.txt") -replace ('var num = \[.*\]', "var num = [$(@($Num) -join ",")]") | Set-Content "C:\file.txt"
```

it seems to work. I also have extended the Regex to `var num = \[.*\]`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: .Net's [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.1#Methods) doesn't support regex. There's a class in `System.Text.RegularExpressions`, but using it is quite overkill when `-replace` works as per your answer.

Comment: @nitin chawda: Please mark the question as solved, if the answer is ok for you. Thx